# PIN number to asterisk "*"

Tags: c++, passwords, turbo-c

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int c,p,p1,p2,p3,Strans, Ctrans;
float amount;
int Cbalance = 5000;
int Sbalance = 10000;
char print;

void transaction(){
            clrscr();
            cout<<"Choose your transaction:";
            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t(1) Balance Inquiry\t\t(2) Withdrawal";
            cout<<"\n\nSelect an Option: ";
            cin>>p1;
            //BALANCE INQUIRY
            if(p1==1){
                clrscr();
                cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t(1) Current\t\t(2) Savings";
                cout<<"\n\nSelect an Option: ";
                cin>>p2;
                //Balance Inquiry CURRENT
                if(p2==1){
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Print Receipt?: ";
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    (1) Yes (2) No";
                    cout<<"\n\nChoose Option: ";
                    cin>>print;
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Your balance is: "<<Cbalance;
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Ctrans;
                        if(Ctrans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Ctrans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }

                }
                //Balance Inquiry SAVINGS
                else if(p2==2){
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Print Receipt?: ";
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    (1) Yes (2) No";
                    cout<<"\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                    cin>>print;
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Your balance is: "<<Sbalance;
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                    cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                    cin>>Strans;
                    if(Strans==1){
                        transaction();
                    }
                    if(Strans==2){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                        cout<<"\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                    }
                    else{
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                }
            }
            //WITHDRAWAL
            else if(p1==2){
                clrscr();
                cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t(1) Current\t\t(2) Savings";
                cout<<"\n\nSelect an Option: ";
                cin>>p3;
                //Withdrawal CURRENT
                if(p3==1){
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter Amount: ";
                    cin>>amount;
                    if(amount <= 0){
                        clrscr();
                        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t      Invlaid Amount.";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                    }
                    if(amount > 0&&amount < 100){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Minimum amount is 100";
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Ctrans;
                        if(Ctrans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Ctrans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                    if(amount>Cbalance){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInsuficient funds!";
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Ctrans;
                        if(Ctrans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Ctrans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                    if(amount<=Cbalance&&amount>=100){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tBalance: "<<Cbalance - amount;
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Strans;
                        if(Strans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Strans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card and count your money before leaving.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Withdrawal SAVINGS
                else if(p3==2){
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter Amount: ";
                    cin>>amount;
                    if(amount <= 0){
                        clrscr();
                        cout << "\n\n\n\t\t\t       Invalid Amount.";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                    }
                    if(amount > 0&&amount < 100){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t    Minimum amount is 100";
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Strans;
                        if(Strans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Strans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                    if(amount>Sbalance){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInsuficient funds!";
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Strans;
                        if(Strans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Strans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                    if(amount<=Sbalance&&amount>=100){
                        clrscr();
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tBalance: "<<Sbalance - amount;
                        cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\t\t   Do you want to have another transaction?";
                        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t        (1) Yes (2) No";
                        cout<<"\n\n\nChoose Option (1 or 2): ";
                        cin>>Strans;
                        if(Strans==1){
                            transaction();
                        }
                        if(Strans==2){
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
                            cout<<"\n\t    Please get your card and count your money before leaving.";
                        }
                        else{
                            clrscr();
                            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    clrscr();
                    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
                }
            }
            else{
                clrscr();
                cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
                cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
            }

}

void main(){
    clrscr();
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t   -----------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"\t\t   WELCOME TO BANK OF THE PHILIPPINE ISLANDS\n ";
    cout<<"\t\t   -----------------------------------------\n";
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t      (1) Continue\t\t(2) Exit";
    cout<<"\n\n\n\nSelect an Option (1 or 2):  ";
    cin>>c;
    //CONTINUE
    if(c==1){
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter your PIN: ";
        cin>>p;
        //TRANSACTION
        if(p==1234){
            transaction();

        }
        else{
            clrscr();
            cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\t   Wrong PIN!";
            cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
        }
    }
    //EXIT
    else if(c==2){
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\tThank you for banking with us.";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
    }
    else{
        clrscr();
        cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Input!";
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";
    }
}
getch();
```

> **I'm making an ATM interface on C++ for a school project of my friend. How can i change the PIN number into asterisks "*"? P.S. the
> pin number codes are in the MAIN. thanks :D**
>
> **I'm making an ATM interface on C++ for a school project of my friend. How can i change the PIN number into asterisks "*"? P.S. the
> pin number codes are in the MAIN. thanks :D**

Comment: In the future, it would be worth posting a smaller code sample that demonstrates your problem instead of a giant blob of code with your problem buried somewhere inside

Comment: Was it really necessary to dump five pages of code into the question, when you could have just asked, "How can I read a number from `cin` but display asterisks instead of the characters entered?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getch()` like this:

```
int i=1;
cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter your PIN: ";
while((p=getch()) != '\n' && p==i) {
    i++;
    cout<<"*";
}
if(i==5)   
    transaction();            
else {        
    clrscr();         
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\t   Wrong PIN!";         
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";         
}
```

Or like this:

```
int i=0,pin[4]={0};
cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter your PIN: ";
while((pin[i]=getch()) != '\n' && i<4) {
    i++;
    cout<<"*";
}
if(pin[0]==1 && pin[1]==2 && pin[2]==3 && pin[3]==4)   
    transaction();            
else {        
    clrscr();         
    cout<<"\n\n\n\t\t\t\t   Wrong PIN!";         
    cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t    Please get your card.";         
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work :( the first time i press a key on the keyboard, the "wrong pin! Please get your card" pops out.

Comment: Did you type 1234 ? If yes,try the edited code. Accept the answer if it worked!

Comment: "1234" already worked but when i enter a different pin it doesn't input and when i enter 1 as first digit and any number other than 2 as second digit it deletes the first digit that i entered.

Comment: So tell the maximum length of the pin

Comment: the maximum length is 4

Comment: Now try it and accept my answer if it helped !

Comment: when i press enter after inputing the pin the program terminates

Comment: hey can i have the first codes that you've posted before editing it? i think i copied it wrong.

Comment: The one starting with int  or char ?

Comment: the first one that you answered.

Comment: It won't work when you enter a wrong integer.